# java asynchronous sockets - which reply belongs to which request?

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, memcached

I have a general question concerning asynchronous **socket-I/O** in Java I could nowhere find the answer to:

Say I send 3 requests through a socket using **TCP** to a particular server asynchronously, meaning, without waiting for the response of a request before sending the next one. As far as I understand, I can do that by using, for instance, **Java NIO** and the non-blocking **SocketChannel** in one single thread. Now, say I get 2 responses back, and the server processes requests in the order it receives them. Is there a way for me to determine to which of my 3 requests the responses belong to? After all, I have no guarantee that my requests arrive at the server in the same order as I sent them..right? Is there any library (perhaps other than **Java.NIO**) that could help me in assigning responses to requests?

Looking forwards to your responses. *Many* thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If**, as you say, **you use TCP the order is guaranteed** (within a  connection).
**And if**, as you say, server **processes** requests in the order it receives them **and sends** responses in that particular order, responses order will correspond requests order. So you assign them by the order.

But if the software we are talking about is developed by you (your team), you'd better include some **request id** in the client-server protocol, this will help you in assigning responses to requests without having to depend on the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [Network Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), socket pair is described as 4-tuple, if the protocol you are using is TCP, then you have both local and remote ip + port of the request.

Let's say you send 3 requests, you can see where the data is coming from (remote ip + port) for each socket.

Comment: Hi Erik,

Thanks for the reply. But can I also assign replies to requests when I'm using only one socket for the entire communication with the server? (i.e. all requests are sent through the same socket)

Comment: Well think of a socket as a pipe, let's say you are sending http request through that socket, you will have to wait for a response before you can make another request, because there is a protocol for sending things over this pipe. So yeah it will have to be synchronous if you want to use one socket (On the other hand, you can change the protocol to support up to 3 request or something like that but you must teach the other peer this protocol and by doing that you must make clear in what order he is going to answer the requests)